# How to add textview small texts

Tags: java, android, textview

i want to make a program. I have 16 textviews that includes letters. And i want to add small text to every textview -programmatically-. Please refer to the pictures..

[firstly --> picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKzX9.png)

[after adding --> picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tC9r.png)

Comment: There's something called a `RecyclerView` that supports grid layout. Create a single layout file with two `TextView`'s in it, according to your design. Inflate them in your RecyclerView and show/hide the second text view whenever required.

Comment: There's also something called a `GridView`... much more straightforward

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20671887/make-a-text-view-overlay-another-text-view

Answer (score 0):

You may do this:

Instead of getting textviews into the program, you can create a layout file which contains 2 text views. You may need to use "layers" to do this. One for big text, other one for the little text which contains the reduced size texts. Then inflate the layout file to a view by an inflater. Then use that view instead of textview. So you have little numbers on you table now.

I don't know about RecyclerView, may be that can be a better solution but as i said i dont know it so here is my answer, good luck at your project!